# Can I modify indexes or views to improve 'is null' clause performance

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query that runs in 4 seconds without an `is null` in the WHERE, but takes almost a minute with an `is null`.  I've read up on the performance impact of the null check, but in this case, I can't modify the query being run.

```
select 
    view_scores.* 
from 
    view_scores
    inner join licenses AS l on view_scores.studentId = l.account_id
where view_scores.archived_date is null 
    and l.school_id = 'aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee' 
    and l.is_current = 1 
    and l.expiration_date >= SYSDATETIME()
```

view_scores is a view that aggregates other views of data in other tables, one of which ultimately holds the archived_date field.  A null value in that field means it hasn't been archived.  Again, the data structure is outside of my control.  All I can currently change is the internals of the views involved and indexes on the tables.  Do I have any hope of dramatically improving the null check on archived_date without changing the query or schema?

`view_scores` is created with this SQL

```
SELECT 
    ueh.user_id AS studentId,
    vu.first_name + ' ' + vu.last_name AS studentName,
    ueh.archived_date as archived_date,
    MIN([ueh].[date_taken]) AS [started_date],
    MAX(ueh.date_taken) AS last_date,
    SUM(CAST([ueh].[actual_time] AS FLOAT) / 600000000) AS [total_time_minutes],
    SUM([exercise_scores].[earned_score]) AS [earned_score],
    SUM([exercise_scores].[possible_score]) AS [possible_score],
    AVG([exercise_scores].[percent_score]) AS [percent_score],
    COUNT(ueh.exercise_id) AS total_exercises
FROM [user_exercise_history] AS [ueh]
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            coding_exercise_score.exercise_id AS exercise_id,
            coding_exercise_score.assessment_id AS assessment_id,
            coding_exercise_score.user_id AS user_id,
            coding_exercise_score.archived_date AS archived_date,
            score.earned AS earned_score,
            score.possible AS possible_score,
            CASE score.possible
                WHEN 0 THEN 0
                WHEN score.earned THEN 100
                ELSE 9.5 * POWER(CAST(score.earned AS DECIMAL) / score.possible * 100, 0.511)
            END AS percent_score
        FROM coding_exercise_score
        INNER JOIN
            coding_exercise_score_detail AS score_detail
            ON coding_exercise_score.id = score_detail.exercise_score_id
        INNER JOIN
            score
            ON score.id = score_detail.score_id
        WHERE score_detail.is_best_score = 'True'

        UNION

        SELECT
            mc_score.exercise_id AS exercise_id,
            mc_score.assessment_id AS assessment_id,
            mc_score.user_id AS user_id,
            mc_score.archived_date AS archived_date,
            score.earned AS earned_score,
            score.possible AS possible_score,
            CASE score.possible
                WHEN 0 THEN 0
                WHEN score.earned THEN 100
                ELSE 9.5 * POWER(CAST(score.earned AS DECIMAL) / score.possible * 100, 0.511)
            END AS percent_score
        FROM
            multiple_choice_exercise_score AS mc_score
        INNER JOIN score
            ON score.id = mc_score.score_id
    ) AS [exercise_scores] 
        ON
            (
                (ueh.exercise_id = [exercise_scores].exercise_id 
                    AND ueh.user_id = [exercise_scores].user_id 
                    AND (
                        (ueh.assessment_id IS NULL AND [exercise_scores].assessment_id IS NULL) 
                        OR ueh.assessment_id = [exercise_scores].assessment_id
                        )
                    AND (ueh.archived_date IS NULL) 
                )
            )
INNER JOIN entity_account AS vu ON ((ueh.user_id = vu.account_id)) 
INNER JOIN (
    select
        g.group_id,
        g.entity_name,
        g.entity_description,
        g.created_on_date,
        g.modified_date,
        g.created_by,
        g.modified_by,
        agj.account_id
    from entity_group as g
    inner join
        account_group_join as agj
    on agj.group_id = g.group_id
    where g.entity_name <> 'Administrators'
        and g.entity_name <> 'Group 1'
        and g.entity_name <> 'Group 2'
        and g.entity_name <> 'Group 3'
        and g.entity_name <> 'Group 4'
        and g.entity_name <> 'Group 5'
) AS g ON ueh.user_id = g.account_id
WHERE ueh.status = 'Completed'  
GROUP BY ueh.user_id, vu.first_name, vu.last_name, ueh.archived_date
```

`user_exercise_history.archived_date AS archived_date` being the field that the null check is ultimately being executed against.  I can modify the view in any way I want and index in any way I want, but that's about it.

The execution plan with the null check in it includes a pretty crazy set of sorting and Hash Matches that pertain to the score and coding_exercise_score_detail.

[image: Execution Plan Details]

Comment: `EXEC sp_updatestats;` to update stats on your db.Any change?

Comment: So If you can change the internals of the view, can we see the view creation sql?

Comment: Are you calling any other views in the view? That is frequently a bad idea if so. We almost lost a multi-million dollar client because someone who didn't know any better designed the whole thing around views that call views.

Comment: Updated the question with the views.  This was all inherited SQL.  =]

Comment: There the issue, you are doing exactly the same mistake pointed by @HLGEM. Your create view statement is fetching data from other view instead of original tables.

Comment: @HLGEM, you should post that comment as answer.

Comment: I moved all of the SQL to the one view from any other views being called (fun) with no improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an index on a view.
[Create Indexed Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx)
Try an index on view_scores.archived_date

Comment: My understanding is that you can only index a view with deterministic values.  Some of the columns are SUM or AVG or COUNT which is non-deterministic if I understand.  That makes this impossible, correct?

Comment: You can create a index on view only if you want to make it a Indexed/materialized view. probably OP don't want that.

Comment: Sadly very few views actually meet the criteria for being indexed.

Comment: @sonicblis Detail not in the question

Comment: Too true.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Generally all the columns involved in `JOIN ON` condition and in `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` should be indexed for better performance. Since you said `view_scores` is a view then check whether the column `archived_date` in actual table is indexed or not. If not then you should consider creating an index on that column.

You may also consider adding that condition to the view creation logic itself.

```
view_scores.archived_date is null
```

Comment: Adding a non-clustered index on that field had no impact.  Adding a clustered index on that field made performance worse.

Comment: Is it a datetime column? also can you include that coolumn in view creation itself.

Comment: it is a datetime that (obviously) allows nulls.  How do you mean include it in the view itself?  Right now the view is returning it as a column.  select ... ueh.archived_date as archived_date ..., ueh being another view that is returning the actual field archived_date.

Comment: Updated the question with the views involved.

Answer (score 0):

```
ON      ueh.exercise_id = [exercise_scores].exercise_id 
    AND ueh.user_id     = [exercise_scores].user_id 
    AND ueh.archived_date IS NULL 
    AND ( (     ueh.assessment_id IS NULL   
            AND [exercise_scores].assessment_id IS NULL
          ) 
          OR ueh.assessment_id = [exercise_scores].assessment_id
        )
```

I would look at this
OR in Join is typically slow
Pick and ID that will not be used

```
ON      ueh.exercise_id = [exercise_scores].exercise_id 
    AND ueh.user_id     = [exercise_scores].user_id 
    AND ueh.archived_date IS NULL 
    AND isnull(ueh.assessment_id, -1) = isnull([exercise_scores].assessment_id, -1)
```